# PHP How to test a value of standard class object

Tags: php

I would like to check if the value of a standard class object has a value of 'None'. The object is a PDO and pulls data from the database.

Here is the data from a var_dump:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[8]
      public 'Subid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'id' => string '27' (length=2)
      public 'english' => string 'English Standard' (length=16)
      public 'maths' => string 'Mathematics General 2' (length=21)
      public 'hsie1' => string 'Modern History' (length=14)
      public 'science1' => string 'Biology' (length=7)
      public 'science2' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'science3' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'tech1' => string 'Agriculture' (length=11)
      public 'tech2' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'extension' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'arts1' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'arts2' => string 'Dance' (length=5)
      public 'pdhpe1' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'vet1' => string 'None' (length=4)
      public 'start_time' => string '2016-11-15 19:54:08' (length=19)
```

Is it possible to loop through the keys and test the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can foreach over an array and the public properties of an object

So

```
foreach ( $array as $obj ) {

    foreach ( $obj as $prop => $val ) {
        if ( $val == 'None' ) {
            echo $prop . ' = ' . $val;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I dont see why you had to change anything here is a quick test I ran

```
$o = new stdClass;
$o->p1 = 1;
$o->p2 = 'two';
$o->p3 = 'None';

$array = array($o);

var_dump($array);


foreach ( $array as $obj ) {

    foreach ( $obj as $prop => $val ) {
        if ( $val == 'None' ) {
            echo $prop . ' = ' . $val;
        }
    }
}
```

And the results were

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class stdClass#1 (3) {
    public $p1 => int(1)
    public $p2 => string(3) "two"
    public $p3 => string(4) "None"
  }
}
p3 = None
```

Comment: You win! (But you're assigning, not comparing!)

Comment: I still don't get it. Where does the array come from? How does it get loaded?

Comment: Ok, I had to do this first and then it worked. { BTW, this was my 1st post. Thank you and peace to this community! }

Comment: foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;
 }

Comment: You did not mention that you wanted to store the results in an array